# Vue.js lazy load custom library component

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, umd

I've created a small library with 2 components and compile it in UMD.
I export components like that :

```
import Btn from './components/Btn'
import Other from './components/Other'

export { Btn, Other }
```

I've tried to use lazy import or export as default... not better.
In my app, i import library as npm dependency.
After, in app.vue, I would like to load a component (like Btn) with lazy loading

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Btn: () => import('myLib').then(m => m.Btn)
  }
}
```

That's work but it's not good for me because all library is load and after I use Btn.
There is a way to load directly component with true lazy load ?

Another way is to full lazy load library a the first use...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am running into this now that I am moving to a monorepo structure

Comment: BTW, the way that I am doing it now is to only have one component in a library if I want to dynamically load that component. I only have a handful of components that fall into that category so it is ok for now. But a general solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested).  Instead of immediately importing modules in your library, export functions.  Remove all `import` statements from the library:

**<library>.js**

```js
export default {
  Btn: () => import('./components/Btn'),
  Other: () => import('./components/Other')
}
```

Use it like:

```js
import myLib from './myLib'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Btn: myLib.Btn
  }
}
```

You can do it without a library too:

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Btn: () => import('./components/Btn')
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but doesn't work


[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function Btn() {
      return Promise.resolve(/*! import() */).then(__webpack_require__.t.bind(null, /*! fragment */ "../lib/dist/fragment.umd.min.js", 7)).then(function (m) {
        console.log(m);
        m.Btn();
      });
    }
Reason: TypeError: m.Btn is not a function

Comment: That's why one should never post answers without testing...  I updated with a tested answer.

Comment: It's almost that :D Do you try with vue-cli ? By default, webpack split library with 3 chunks : library + Btn + Other. So now i've this error : 

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function Btn() {
          return n.e(1).then(n.bind(null, "dedc"));
        }
Reason: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:8080/js/myLib.umd.min.1.js)

I push all code under github : https://github.com/BriceChaponneau/vue-lib

Comment: Yes, I tested in Vue CLI

Comment: Hummm ok. So what's wrong in my code please ? It could not be more easy.

Comment: Maybe because UMD?  I'm not familiar with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225229/discussion-between-brice-chaponneau-and-dan).